# How should I set the value for my model using a select control when the bound model is a different type from my select option?

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, angular-material, entity-framework-core

I've been using AngularJS for a long time and have recently been diving into the new Angular and .NET Core.  With my new endeavor, I began learning the vast changes in Entity Framework Core.  One of the most impactful changes relates to many-to-many relationships.  Previously, you had the ability to hide the join table which aligned nicely with AngularJS, because the navigation property on the ngModel could be the same type as the option value.  Now that this is no longer a thing, we must find a means of converting from one entity to another.  Here's my models:

Transaction.cs

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }


    public virtual IList<CategoryTransaction> CategoryTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

Category.cs

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }


    public virtual IList<CategoryTransaction> CategoryTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

CategoryTransaction.cs

```
public class CategoryTransaction
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public int TransactionId { get; set; }


    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using TypeScript and have defined my models and my markup form looks like this:

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn" placeholder="Categories" [(ngModel)]="testTransaction.categoryTransactions" multiple name="foo">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categoryList" [value]="category">{{ category.name }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

and here is my compareFn:

```
compareFn(category: Category, categoryTransaction: CategoryTransaction) {
    return categoryTransaction && category ? categoryTransaction.categoryId === category.id : false;
}
```

I got here and started thinking: "How am I going to convert from `Category` to `CategoryTransaction`?  I was looking around for ways to sorta "hook into" the model setter event and create a `CategoryTransaction` object using the selected `Category`, but I haven't been able to find a means of hooking in.  Then I saw in a post that you could use `JSON` in the value attribute.  So I altered my markup and compare function to this:

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn2" placeholder="Categories" [(ngModel)]="testTransaction.categoryTransactions" multiple name="foo">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categoryList" [value]="{ categoryId: category.id, transactionId: 1 }">{{ category.name }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

and

```
compareFn2(c1: CategoryTransaction, c2: CategoryTransaction) {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.categoryId === c2.categoryId : false;
}
```

It works, but I don't like it.  It feels messy/hackish and doesn't seem to fit into the "Angular Way" where we're working with objects.  I don't think the view should be where we convert values.  What I imagined I would be doing would be "new-ing up" a `CategoryTransaction` and setting the value or implementing some value converter.  Since I would be converting/setting the value in TypeScript, if my model changes, the TypeScript compiler would hopefully complain if I missed it.

So this seems like a common scenario (many-to-many) that people must've encountered with EF Core + Angular, but I'm having issues finding a good example.  Has anyone found a good way to handle this scenario or perhaps has a good example for overriding the ngModel value using a select control?

I'm using `.NET Core 2.1`, `Angular 7.0.4`, `Material 7.0.4`, and `EF Core Sql Server 2.1.4`.

Comment: From reading your question, I couldn't capture what's your problem. Is the back-end working normally, and you just want to know how to present the data? I would say, don't return the models as they are to outside world.. you can create a `CategoryViewModel` that hide away the n-to-n relationship.. your front-end shouldn't care about it too much. While saving, you just send both id's and the back-end takes care of it.

Comment: Not a problem.  My real issue lies with this part right here: `[value]="{ categoryId: category.id, transactionId: 1 }"`.  I don't think I should have to put JSON in the markup to convert from one type to the other.  I think I found a solution though which I'll post shortly.  The issue isn't in the backend/saving.  It's in the model-binding on the front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `<mat-select>` I decided to subscribe to the `selectionChange` event and see what it would provide me.

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn" placeholder="Categories" [(ngModel)]="testTransaction.categoryTransactions" multiple name="foo" (selectionChange)="categoryChange($event, testTransaction)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categoryList" [value]="category">{{ category.name }}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

I passed it the `$event` argument and the `Transaction` object.

```
// Respond to when the selection changes
categoryChange(event: MatSelectChange, transaction: Transaction) {
    // Rather than trying to manually detect what changed, just clear out all the options
    transaction.categoryTransactions = [];
    // Iterate through all the selected options
    for (var i: number = 0; i < event.value.length; i++) {
      // Add a new CategoryTransaction for each selected Category
      transaction.categoryTransactions.push({
        transactionId: transaction.id,
        categoryId: event.value[i].id
      });
    }
}
```

The `$event` object parameter passes all the selected `Category` objects and the `Transaction` parameter is the object that holds all the join table entries.  I was afraid that by changing the `transaction.categoryTransactions` which is bound to the `ngModel` I might be stuck in an infinite loop of the `selectionChange` event firing, but to my relief, that didn't turn out to be the case.

Comment: you have experience in Angular and .net core, can you please guide me i have a drop down in angular 9 and want to pass the selected value to controller as parameter without using jquery (with binding). I have implemented everything but the issue is in passing selected value. Shall i do it by creating a service?